# WooCommerce product rating showing wrong on google using yoast plugin

Tags: woocommerce, yoast

issue with structured data sometimes reporting rating of 3.9 regardless of real product average on google.

search this on google "teeccino dandelion" http://prntscr.com/kl3i2j. When you  visit that product and found 5 star rating on the web site. see this: http://prntscr.com/kl3ir6

Where this rating calculate?. This is issue with Yoast plugin?.

Please help me on this.

Thanks

Comment: Could be that google hasn't scraped the website again. How long ago was the rating updated?

Comment: Thanks for replied. but when I see the source of product page then found wrong value of rating in the schema. check this: http://prntscr.com/kl3omn